# Why my sites can't show the event content from CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, multisite

The project has been set up as multisite.

If I am trying to get the contents by https://**111**.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=1. Everything works well.

But if I change it to https://**222**.com/civicrm/page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=1. It just shows [Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM.]

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Is CiviCRM network-activated? Or per-site? Sounds like there's no CiviCRM active on your second domain.

Comment: Can anyone help me?? I am waiting online

Comment: by 'online' do you mean chat.civicrm.org - if so pls cross-reference. also pls remember we are all helping each other voluntarily here

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Yes, the civiCRM is network-activated. The problem is that when I setup the domain to AAA, all sites will use AAA as their domain. Also, if I go to another site to setup domain with BBB, all sites will use BBB. So, I can't separate the sites. I want to know how to setup them separately. Is there any details? Thanks again.